# Problemas con un future en app de Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, app, widget

Estoy haciendo un aplicación simple de clima, con la API de OpenWeather, y me arroja el siguiente error: "The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#9133d):
type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'Weather?' in type cast"

El Código el el siguiente:

```
  Future getForecast(Location location) async {
  Forecast forecast;
  String apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  String lat = location.lat;
  String lon = location.lon;
  var url =
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=$lat&lon=$lon&appid=$apiKey&units=metric";

  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    forecast = Forecast.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  }

  return _forecast;
}

class _forecast {
}
```

Soy nueva en esto, y he probado muchas formas, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar. Agradecería alguien me pueda decir el error y como solucionarlo. Gracias!

Comment: estás esperando un `Forecast` de respuesta, pero veo que abajo has declarado una clase rara:  `_forecast`. La variable que usas para asignar el forecast es "forecast" , pero retornas un "_forecast" revisa bien.

Comment: prueba esto -> Future<Forecast> getForecast(Location location) async {